# How many different techniques of meditation did Buddha teach?

Tags: meditation-recommendation

I was just wondering how many different types of meditation techniques did Buddha teach?

I know the below

Anapana, 
Vipassana, 
Charnal Ground, 
Metta Bhavana,

I am looking for a list of meditations for my research purpose.

Answer (score 2):

> Anapana, Vipassana, 32 body parts meditation, Metta Bhavana,
>
> I am looking for a list of meditations for my research purpose.

They're parts of what's called the Kammatthana, the Forty objects of meditation as classified in the [Visuddhimagga](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf). The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamma%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADh%C4%81na) also gives a pretty good summary about them.

Answer (score 2):

The Buddha described practice in several different ways. For example:

The phrase "practice like this" occurs in at least 26 suttas: sn54.10 sn54.1 sn54.13 an10.29 sn54.9 sn54.8 sn54.7 sn54.6 sn54.5 sn54.4 sn54.3 sn54.20 an3.60

The phrase "practice the meditation" occurs in at least 2 suttas: MN151 MN121

The phrase "practicing the right way" occurs in at least 1 sutta: MN139

The phrase "here we will" occurs in at least 1 sutta: MN8

The phrase "immersion that does not lean forward" occurs in at least 1 sutta: AN9.37

The phrase "with teeth clenched" occurs in at least 4 suttas: MN20 MN100 MN36 MN85

There are no doubt many others...to find them please read the suttas. That is what researchers themselves do.